# How to escape pipeline char in Windows shell?

Tags: windows, shell, regular-expressions, escaping

I need to specify a regular expression that includes `|` character to `findstr` command:

```
processtext.exe | findstr /R "Hello|Bye"
```

How do I escape it? `\|` does not work. Quotes fix issue with pipelining but the regex does not match although separate searches for "Hello" and "Bye" do. I'm interested in a solution for legacy shell, not powershell.

Comment: Have you tried encapsulating it in quotation marks? What does your entire script look like?

Comment: Are you sure findstr supports pipe syntax (this|that matching)? Not seeing anything in the documentation.

Comment: [FINDSTR support for regular expressions is limited and non-standard](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html). FINDSTR does not support alternation with the `|` pipe character...

Answer (score -1):

If someone is still interested just replace the pipe with a space, like in findstr /R "Hello Bye".

Answer (score -1):

I've found a solution for my purposes of running powershell commands from cmd.exe as follows:

```
C:\GitLab-Runner>powershell get-service *gitlab* ^| ft
```

to get following output

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  gitlab-runner      gitlab-runner
```

Comment: This doesn't even remotely address the question.

Comment: The point is that using `^|` worked for my command to escape the pipe character correctly. At least, it is a chance that the `^` char works for your requirement, too. 
If not, this answer might at least be helpful for other persons searching for a solution in combination with other commands (like `powershell`).

Comment: For your reference, you might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200235/how-to-pass-a-quoted-pipe-character-to-cmd-exe which provides some solutions for similar challenge